# .htaccess no SSL only on home but SSL everywhere else?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like that the .htaccess don't add the SSL on the home link

> http://domain.com

but on every other links in the website

> https://domain.com/folder/index.html

So only the home page would not be secure. What the best .htaccess config for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RewriteRule` to match that *anything* is present beyond the `/` and if matched, rewrite to SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If ssl is not already active
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# .+ matches one or more of any character... An empty string would not match
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST]}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.+$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```